# How to decomment an html/php webpage?

Tags: php, html, comments, performance

A crazy question:

Imagine a webpage file called `somepage.php`
And it contains some html php contents in my editor I see:

```
<html><head></head><body>  
<?=$welcome . $essay . $thatsAllForNowFolks . $footer ?>

<!--
Blue
Ball
Bell
Blow
Bows
Bats
Beef
Bark
Bill
Boss

-->
</body></html>
```

When I browse my site I see those comments in the final result, while I only want that comment to be only in my editor for my secretive inspirations and don't want the whole world to know what I'm thinking when I'm developing, as well as I see those comments for any and all my website visitors as wasted bandwitch of internet speed.

How do I *decomment* my entire html/php files at the moment the html is served?
Ideas, code and suggestions are much appreciated. My thanks in advance...

Comment: how long did it take for you to get all thos 4 letter words :P wordbee

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone, I dont know how long it took me to get all those 4 letter words since I didnt time it. I will time now exactly 90 seconds and within this timescope I might get some more (stressfull!)... starting (where is my stopwatch oy here) starting NOW:  `beam... bake... book... biff... bike... beat... bits... boat... bend... bing`... times up and actually i'm not sure if the last one is a word or not. I guese I'm one of those guys who perform better under pressure, albeit a mere 1 word per 10 seconds my neural engine runs, apparently at 0,0000000001 GHZ. Yikes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the same as Michiel's approach but I'm lazy so I would use the abbreviated  tags, just be sure you have short_open_tag set to 1 in your php.ini config.

```
<html><head></head><body>  
<?=$welcome . $essay . $thatsAllForNowFolks . $footer ?>

<? /*
Blue
Ball
Bell
Blow
Bows
Bats
Beef
Bark
Bill
Boss

*/ ?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Please note that you will need to have short tags enabled in your server configuration to be able to write PHP code this way.

Comment: The lazy person (me) now needs to change PHP settings just to to enable short tags... all of that extra load of workpile just sothat the lazy person can keep lazy habits (and the accompanying extra workloads thereafter)... pfff

Answer (score 14):

Probably the easiest solution is to write your comments in PHP. This way they will not be sent to the client in the source code. You can do it like this:

```
<html>

<?php
    //A single comment

    /*
         Some more
         comments
    */
?>

</html>
```

Comment: +1 @Michiel Pater for those two fashions `//...` and `/* ... */`  Dreamweaver seems also to say that `# .....` is okay and even `<?php /*?> ... <?php */?>` are there any others I am missing? which one would you recommend me using (I like consistency: chosing one, and going with that one)

Comment: @Sam: Oops, I incidentally pressed CTRL + R instead of CTRL + T. So now I have to rewrite the whole long message...

Comment: @Michiel, oops I know Ctr+R refreshed the entire page with fresh empty boxes?! hmmm.. By the way do you know what @ianhales means byt combining your code with @Grad  ? Curious...

Comment: @Sam: Personally I am using `<?php` to start writing PHP, because it will work on every server. Also, I usually open and close PHP only once in a page as switching between PHP code and HTML takes time. I then use `echo` to display my HTML code. As for the comments it depends. For single row comments I am using `//`. For comments on multiple rows I use `/* */`. If I want to temporarily comment out one line of code, I use `#`. I am doing this to distinguish between normal comments and code that has been temporarily commented out.

Comment: @Sam: He means to load your HTML into a PHP variable and remove the comments using something like a function. I prefer using always PHP for commenting though.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the complexity of your pages/comments.

You could strip them out using strpos and str_replace, or maybe a regular expressions.
But HTML isn't a *regular language*, so the best way would be using a DOM parser, stripping out the comments.

(You could register your function as a output filter in php, using the output buffering functions like ob_start)

Comment: This, combined with following Michiel Pater's advice from hereonin sounds like the best plan.

Comment: @ianhales, how do you mean? how to achieve that combination? You are most welcome to share your thoughts and codes with all of us.

Comment: I mean, for the pages you've already done, you can use a DOM parser to remove any HTML comments that you don't want showing to the world. Then in future when you make new pages, encase your comments in PHP tags and use the PHP comment style (i.e. `//` for single line and `/* */` for multi-line. Any clearer?